# Is there an alternative to add_header_lines for flextable?

Tags: flextable

I am trying to add a simple header to my flextable objects. When I was looking at the following [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/layout.html), I found a description of the add_header_lines function. However, when I tried this on my own table, I got an error telling me that the function does not exist. Is there a simple alternative to this function? I know that there is the add_header function, though it seems this requires column keys to work (and that the header must be set for each column key and then merged), which is a bit tedious for data sets with many columns.

I was wondering if there was a good alternative to add_header_lines? Or is the only way to add a header with add_header and column keys?

Comment: maybe you just need to update your package?

Comment: ... I can't believe that worked. I'm very surprised given I installed flextable only a month or so ago!

I'm slightly embarrassed. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: don't worry :) good it worked

Answer (score 0):

The Reproters package is deprecated from R 3.6 version. Try Officer or other packages to work on the same.